# Reading excel with python when keys are not in first row

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read a lot of excel files in a folder that have the same format. My keys are not in the first row, so when I run this code, I gives me

```
KeyError: '"A"'
```

it's tricky as well because the name of my columns are "A" (with the citation marks). How can I have it go through every file and read the data for each column in each file?[image: Excel Format]

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
import scipy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import gridspec
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import scipy.stats as st


#GUI
root=Tk()
root.withdraw() #closes tkinter window pop-up
path=filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,title='Choose a folder')
path=path+'/'

print('Folder Selected',path)
files=os.listdir(path)
length=len(files)

print('Files inside the folder',files)

Files=[]

for s in os.listdir(path):
    Files.append(pd.read_excel(path+s))

#initialize arrays
A=[None]*length
B=[None]*length
C=[None]*length

for filenumber in range(0,length):  
    A[filenumber]         = Files[filenumber]['"A"']
    B[filenumber]      = Files[filenumber]['"B"']
    C[filenumber]         = Files[filenumber]['"C"']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose whatever row to use for the column header:

```
Files.append(pd.read_excel(path+s), header=2);
```

for example, this reads the headers from the 3rd row

See documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the columns and skip the first 2 rows. Then I was able to easily index the different keys

```
data=[None]*length  

for s in range(0,length):
    data[s]=pd.read_excel(files[s],parse_cols="A,B,C,D,E",skiprows=2)

A    = [None]*length

for filenumber in range(0,length):  
    A    [filenumber]      = data[filenumber]['"A"']
```